# Stylusの@importでcssを展開する

Tags: css

Stylusの@importでcssファイルを指定した場合でも，Stylusのファイルを指定した場合のようにファイルの中身を展開したい．

Stylusの文法だけで何とかできないでしょうか？

変換にはgulp-stylusを使っています．

```
# a.css
.a { font-size: 150%; }

# s.styl
@import "a.css"
.s
  font-size 120%

# コンパイル後
@import "a.css"
.s { font-size: 120%; }

# こういう出力が欲しい
.a { font-size: 150%; }
.s { font-size: 120%; }
```

---

追記 gulp-stylusでは下記で出来ました．

```
stylus = require 'gulp-stylus'
..
stylus {'include css':true}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`stylus` コマンドの `--include-css` オプションを使ってCSSへ変換してください。実行例:

```
$ stylus --include-css b.styl
```

このオプションはヘルプに記載がありまして `stylus -h` より抜粋しますと、以下のように説明されています。

```
--include-css           Include regular CSS on @import
```

試してみてください。

---

なお、それが実装されているのは [このあたり](https://github.com/stylus/stylus/blob/9d39b64bb19d784280edd48b0608067a4e0fb37d/lib/visitor/evaluator.js#L880-L886) です。